# Is Two hours of transit at Atlanta airport enough to catch the other flight?

Tags: atlanta

Its my first time traveling in USA, and i will be transit in Atlanta airport for two hours.
I am afraid to lose the next plane to Florida.
Could you please give me any advice what should I do?

Comment: Please add more details about your itinerary. Where are you flying from and to? Which terminals? Which airlines?

Answer (score 2):

Provided that all parts of your journey are booked onto the same ticket, the best advice that can be given is: **Relax!**

Airports and airlines have minimum connection times, and you would not have been able to buy the ticket if the minimum connection time would not be met for your connection. If because of a delay in your incoming flight or long queues at immigration (if you arrive with a non-domestic flight from a non-pre-clearance place), you will miss your outgoing flight, you will be re-booked free of charge by the airline. Obviously you will arrive later then, but at least it doesn't cost anything extra. Also note that before departure of your first flight, that flight is announced to be delayed significantly, you can approach the staff of the airline before departure to already ask for a re-booking.

As already written, if your flight legs are on separate tickets, this does not apply. In fact, 2 hours is rather short unless you are travelling with hand luggage only.

Comment: Don't trust the ticket seller to leave enough time for connections.  Sometimes they do not.  If you are flying into Atlanta (which does not get snow) from a city that does get snow, 2 hours might not be enough.  Check to see if the carrier has a later flight out of Atlanta, in case you miss yours.  Atlanta is somewhat spread out.  But if you walk quickly, you should be fine with 1 hour.  Two hours should be more than enough, no matter if you are switching carriers.  BUT, if you are arriving or departing on an international flight, you probably will need more than two hours.